# Are Chinese social networks "ablaze with antisemitism"?

Tags: china, israel, social-media

This [article](https://mignews.com/news/arabisrael/kitajskie-socseti-polyhayut-ot-antisemitizma.html) with reference to an Israeli diplomat in China says that Chinese social networks are "ablaze with antisemitism".

I wonder if this is true?

Notice also that on the day of the Hamas-announced worldwide pogrom against Jews, an incident occurred only in China where an Israeli diplomat was assaulted.

Answer (score 2):

The question can't be answered satisfactorily because the premise doesn't point to a verifiable statement.

For example, if a Chinese netizen asked you whether Western-style English language social media was filled with X or Y, you would have difficulty answering this question on its own and would instead ask for clarification on the expected parameters to be investigated or analyzed. Or perhaps you would provide an answer based on the subjective impression you gleaned from your own browsing without bothering to establish a statistical conclusion.

The perception of Jewish people and/or of Israel in China [is a complicated topic](https://www.mei.edu/publications/chinas-ambivalent-attitude-towards-judaism) and perhaps worth its own question. Meanwhile, as mentioned in [this page](https://www.statista.com/statistics/278417/number-of-internet-users-in-china/), "China is home to the largest online community in the world. According to estimates, the Chinese internet population was around 1.04 billion in 2022 and would reach 1.18 billion by 2026. By comparison, the internet user-base of the United States was around 307 million in 2022." Therefore, asking about whether that online community is ablaze with a certain topic is only something that could be conclusively answered with a statistical analysis of some sort, and such an analysis does not yet exist. The best we can do is to speculate.

Comment: Strangely, I very rarely encounter the Chinese on the internet (for instance in open-source software projects or sites like Stackexchange). As a comparison, I encounter Russians very often, even on English-language sites.

Comment: @Anixx It's not that strange since they have their own places. They will not join Western sites for the same reason you won't join Chinese ones: the language barrier and unfamiliarity with the online culture there. Russians have many of their own websites but there still is a strong draw and recognition for Western material and culture, whereas it's easier to stay in the Chinese sphere as you have more than enough (the same way anglophones have more than enough)

Comment: @Qwokker - That's only part of the story, and perhaps not even the most important. The other side is that many popular social media websites are just blocked in China: Google, Twitter, Facebook, Tumblr, LinkedIn (there's a separate version for China). Of course, VPNs can be used to bypass this block, but that adds an additional layer of effort. It's much easier to use sites that are not blocked.

Comment: @Obie2.0 this is obviously a factor but in reality even VPN-using Chinese aren't too interested in Western social media. Reddit was unblocked for the longest time and yet never struck any major interest there. If you ask most overseas Chinese students, they'll often say that platforms such as WeChat are inherently better, which is actually a pretty credible argument given their set of features.

Comment: Would the internet have been dominated by Western companies without the Firewall in its early stages? It's entirely possible. However, the idea that the blockage is the only thing preventing Chinese users from embracing Western websites hasn't been accurate for a long time now.